# TinyTex isn't working anymore with rmarkdown (maybe Path problems?)

Tags: r, r-markdown, tex, tinytex

I had a big problem with tinytex. When I tried to knit my document, it said that R can't find "pdflatex". So I tried to reinstall it, but that made things worse! I can't even install tinytex properly right now.

Recently I installed Python and changed something in PATH. So, maybe there lies the problem?
Here is my error:

```
tlmgr search --file --global "/setspace.sty"
Use of uninitialized value $ver in scalar chomp at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLWinGoo.pm line 194.
Use of uninitialized value $ver in substitution (s///) at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLWinGoo.pm line 195.
Use of uninitialized value $ver in substitution (s///) at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLWinGoo.pm line 195.
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2708.
Setting up tar with C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/installer/tar.exe as C:\Users\Fabi\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\tlpkg\installer\tar.exe didn't work
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2691.
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2691.
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2708.
Setting up curl with C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/installer/curl/curl.exe as C:\Users\Fabi\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\tlpkg\installer\curl\curl.exe didn't work
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2691.
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2708.
Setting up wget with C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/installer/wget/wget.exe as C:\Users\Fabi\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\tlpkg\installer\wget\wget.exe didn't work
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2691.
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2708.
Setting up lz4 with C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/installer/lz4/lz4.exe as C:\Users\Fabi\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\tlpkg\installer\lz4\lz4.exe didn't work
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2691.
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2691.
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2708.
Setting up xz with C:/Users/Fabi/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/installer/xz/xz.exe as C:\Users\Fabi\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\tlpkg\installer\xz\xz.exe didn't work
cannot contact mirror.ctan.org, returning a backbone server!

C:\Users\Fabi\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl: TLPDB::from_file could not initialize from: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
C:\Users\Fabi\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl: Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
C:\Users\Fabi\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl: More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html
! LaTeX Error: File `setspace.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *>
```

Comment: Is this link helpful? https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-cant-find-pdflatex/49790

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: What about this? https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-latex-pkgs.html

Comment: sadly not. When I try to install the missing package, I get the same error

Comment: `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()` code will reinstall tinytext, also reinstalling Rmarkdown package has helped me in the past as well

Comment: Tried that already! Uninstalled, reinstalled, manual install of tinytex... but not successful. Reinstalling rmarkdown didn't work, too

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem! It was a problem with my PATH in the environment variables. I added the path to system32 and tlmgr could start the cmd to download all missing packages.